# Is it possible to write an "interconnect" in VHDL by hand?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, intel-fpga, interconnect, microsemi-fpga

An interconnect connects one or more masters to one or more slaves in a sort of system on chip design. In such a scenario there would be a master containing a standard bus like Avalon-MM, AMBA AXI, etc. that needs to connect to multiple slaves.

Provided that we are using one of the standard buses or maybe even something simple, is there a standard way to write interconnect or maybe there is an "off the shelf" component that I can get and use as the interconnect and this can be ported to different FPGA vendor tools?

By hand I mean, not use an automating tool that will just generate the code based on certain input parameters.

Comment: Sure you can, if you have time to waste. Maybe on some open source site you'll find some leads

Comment: Of course it is. Discussed somewhat (for a simpler interconnect than AXI!) here : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/579667/issues-with-bi-directional-data-bus/579672#579672 Note also that some verification technologies ( www.osvvm.org ) include test support for AXI to help keep you on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

One can generally make anything that's auto-generated by hand.  It will usually just take longer than inputting some parameters into an existing tool.

In order to write an automation tool that generates code, the programmer has to know how to write that code by hand.  Otherwise they wouldn't be able to write out the detailed instructions that form the algorithm used by the automation tool.  If you have access to the same documentation there is no reason you can't do the same thing as them.

In order to write an AXI interface you just need to study hundreds of pages of the AXI documentation, understand it, and then write the implementation.  You may also need to study a few hundred more pages of documentation for the technology you plan to implement your code on.

Comment: I assumed that an interconnect would merely consist of muxes and forwarding blocks. Is this not true?

Comment: Not really, there is almost always more to it then that, AXI for example has data/address and command transactions that can happen asynchronously (Yes, even in AXI lite), and the address is NOT guaranteed to be there before the data is. This means that even deciding which downstream device gets the transaction may or may not involve stalling until you have the address.  Writing an AXI device that actually manages to run the bus at one transaction per clock most of the time is way harder then it should be IMHO.